# Return a list from base case in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I have some doubts about how Prolog works.

I have this code bellow (NEW VERSION):

```
listaPessIdade([], Lista).
listaPessIdade([X|Xs], []) :- findall((X, Idade), idade(X, Idade), Lista), listaPessIdade(Xs, Lista).
listaPessIdade([X|Xs], L) :- findall((X, Idade), idade(X, Idade), Lista), listaPessIdade(Xs, [Lista|L]).
```

(OLD VERSION):

```
listPerAge([], [], List, List).
listPerAge([X|Xs]):- listPerAge(X, Xs, []).

listPerAge(Y, [X|Xs], L):- findall((Y, I), age(Y, I), L1), listPerAge(X, Xs, [L1|L]).
listPerAge(Y, [], L):- findall((Y, I), age(Y, I), L1), listPerAge([], [], [L1|L], [L1|L]).
```

And I have a collection of predicates in my KB of the type: `age(person, number)`

But, when I consult `listPerAge([List of persons names])`, the result is **true**
 not the list of lists of persons with your ages.

What is wrong?!

Thanks

Comment: Usually when debugging, a trick is to convince yourself that it works. Usually then you start spotting the errors.

Comment: I try it, but when the execution go to the base case, it begins a recursion and I not expect this reason.

Comment: This is a bit confusing. You have 3 different versions of the `listPerAge` predicate, based on number of arguments. To Prolog, these are different (`listPerAge/1`, `listPerAge/3` and `listPerAge/4`). Your call to `listPerAge([], [], [L1|L], [L1|L])` will always succeed and do nothing since the only rule for `listPerAge/4` is `listPerAge([], [], List, List)` and that clearly matches for any value of `L1` or `L`.

Comment: OK. I will update a new version of my code that produce a empty list.